# How to use shell regex command to split input line into tokens of decimals and operators?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, split, grep

How to use grep/sed/awk to achieve this:

Input: a statement of decimals and numeric operators and parentheses, can have tab and spaces in between:

```
2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8
```

Output: a string, containing each token(either a decimal or an operator or parentheses), seperated by a single comma:

```
2,+,5,*,61.2,-,(,32.5,+,7,),/,8
```

Could regular expression + grep/sed/awk achieve this?

Comment: please add your attempted solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this `sed` solution:

```bash
s='2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8'
sed -E 's~[[:blank:]]*([0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[+/*()-])[[:blank:]]*~\1,~g; s/,$//' <<< "$s"
2,+,5,*,61.2,-,(,32.5,+,7,),/,8
```

Comment: This one is most clear and simple, mark it.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo '2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8' |
sed -Ee 's:[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?|[-+*/()]:&,:g' \
    -e  's/[[:blank:]]+//g' \
    -e  's/,$//'
```

Gives:

```
2,+,5,*,61.2,-,(,32.5,+,7,),/,8
```

Global replace on a regex matching integers, decimal numbers, or one of the six characters `-+*/()`. Then remove tabs and spaces, and trailing comma.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/ |\t//g;s/([-\+\*\/)(])/,\1,/g;s/,+/,/g' <<<"2 + 5* 61.2 -(32.5+7)/ 8"
2,+,5,*,61.2,-,(,32.5,+,7,),/,8
```

Comment: What does s/,,*/,/g mean? @xgadme

Comment: @Troskyvs. changed to `,+`  matche the `,`  between one and unlimited times and replace it with one `,`